# C# .net v4.5 - Response Error in my API Endpoints if I installed Open XML SDK (DocumentFormat.OpenXml v20.0.0) via NuGet

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml-sdk

I am working on a C# .net v4.5 backend as an API. The problem is I get an error right after installing Open XML SDK (DocumentFormat.OpenXml v20.0.0) via NuGet.

This is the error that comes from the response of one of my api endpoints:

**Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1685: Warning as Error: The predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File:    Line: 0

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0**

I have been finding a fix on the internet and using ChatGPT like

- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Deleting the Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Restarting the app

but no luck. I have not found a fix. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Here problem is with your `web.config` file. Please check that way

Comment: Hi @DarshanFaldu, what should I look for on the web.config file that might be causing the error? As I am pretty new to C #.